# PHP/MYSQL: UPDATE query inside a for loop that runs the same query again instead of looping through each item?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm setting a page where there are a couple of configurations.

So I want the page to bring stuff from the database with a SELECT query, show it to the user and for the user to be able to update it and save it into the database with an UPDATE.

### So I have the select query:

```
$buscarTemplates = " SELECT mailNombre, mailAsunto, mailMensaje, mailDetalle
                                 FROM configMailsUsuarios
```

### And I show the list of available options with a `while loop`:

```
$mostrarTemplates = mysqli_query($conectar,$buscarTemplates);
    while ($mails=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrarTemplates)) {

        echo '<h4>'.$mails['mailDetalle'].'</h4>';
        echo '<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="mailNombre" value="'.$mails['mailNombre'].'" readonly>
            <label for="mailAsunto">Asunto:</label>
            <input type="text" name="mailAsunto" value="'.$mails['mailAsunto'].'">
            </div>';
        echo '<textarea class="form-control" name="mailMensaje" rows="4">'.$mails['mailMensaje'].'</textarea>';             
    }
```

### When the user hits the submit button:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $itemsFetched = mysqli_num_rows($mostrarTemplates);
    for ($i=0; $i < $itemsFetched; $i++) { 
        $mailNombre = $_POST['mailNombre'];
        $mailAsunto = $_POST['mailAsunto'];
        $mailMensaje = $_POST['mailMensaje'];
            $guardarTemplates = "UPDATE configMailsUsuarios
                                 SET mailAsunto = '$mailAsunto',
                                     mailMensaje = '$mailMensaje' 
                                 WHERE mailNombre = '$mailNombre'
                                ";
            if (mysqli_query($conectar,$guardarTemplates)) {
                echo 'Configuraciones guardadas exitosamente.<br>';
                echo '<a href="templateMails.php"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="Recargar la página"></input></a><br>';
            } else {
                echo 'Oops!';
            }               
    }
```

The problem is that there are two items in the fetched list, and only the second one gets saved.

```
This is what it is currently in the database table "configMailsUsuarios":

mail ID --- mailNombre ------ mailAsunto ----- mailMensaje -- mailDetalle
1 --------- mailBienvenida -- AvisoA --------- mensajeA ----- XXY
1 --------- mailMorosos ----- AvisoB --------- mensajeB ----- YYX
```

So, I've tried printing out what the query actually returned inside the for loop with `echo $guardarTemplates.'<br>';`
And the result shows that the loop runs twice (as expected), with the new information typed by the user, but **the exact same query, that just takes the second item in the list**:

```
UPDATE configMailsUsuarios SET mailAsunto = 'Aviso2', mailMensaje = 'whatever' WHERE mailNombre = 'mailMorosos' 
UPDATE configMailsUsuarios SET mailAsunto = 'Aviso2', mailMensaje = 'whatever' WHERE mailNombre = 'mailMorosos'
```

The expected result should be taking the first row and updating it, and then the second ones:

```
UPDATE configMailsUsuarios SET mailAsunto = 'Aviso1', mailMensaje = 'blah blah' WHERE mailNombre = 'mailBienvenida' 
UPDATE configMailsUsuarios SET mailAsunto = 'Aviso2', mailMensaje = 'whatever' WHERE mailNombre = 'mailMorosos'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <input type="text" name="mailNombre[]" value="'.$mails['mailNombre'].'" readonly>
        <input type="text" name="mailAsunto[]" value="'.$mails['mailAsunto'].'">
```

Those should be array, otherwise the first gets overwritten by the last one.

Then you have to change your script a little, so it accesses the correct index of your $_POST-array, you have the for-loop already set up so that is good, but you should define it by the number of elements in your request or show us what data is in `$itemsFetched = mysqli_num_rows($mostrarTemplates);`.

You should check out [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) As you are not using prepared statements your script is vulnerable.

In a foreach-loop you could access the fields like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach ($_POST['mailNombre'] as $key => $value) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE configMailsUsuarios 
                                       SET mailAsunto = ?, mailMensaje = ? 
                                       WHERE mailNombre = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $mailNombre, $mailAsunto, $mailMensaje);

        $mailNombre = $_POST['mailNombre'][$key];
        $mailAsunto = $_POST['mailAsunto'][$key];
        $mailMensaje = $_POST['mailMensaje'][$key];

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I should change it to a foreach loop instead? Each one for each array?? And yes, it's just a proof of concept, having added any security yet

Comment: one foreach is enough, added an example. You only need it for the keys to access the fields correctly